# prevent people to see that I use whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

When Alice adds Bob's number to their Android contact list, they can infer whether Bob is using WhatsApp by looking at their WhatsApp contact list. Only if Bob uses WA, they will show up there. How can B disclose their phone number to A while hiding the fact that they use WA?

Comment: Maybe blocking Alice would work? I didn't try it so you'll have to test it yourself. The other option might be to have a different number for WhatsApp or to give out to people

Comment: Depending on the capability of WhatsApp and Android system, what you want to do might be impossible to do with the official WhatsApp. I don't know if modded (unofficial) WhatsApp might help though.